# Close button at Post > Suggested edit > Reject reason closes the suggested edit box

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post with a pending suggested edit (e.g. via the [review suggested edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/)).
2. Click on the "Edit (1)" icon at the question / answer to show a panel <sup>the rightmost X button in the pic below</sup>.
3. Click on the "Reject" button to get another panel <sup>the inner X button in the pic below</sup>.
4. Click on the close button of the second panel.

#### What did I expect?

Clicking on the inner X button should only close the second panel.

#### What happens instead?

Both panels are closed.

[image: reject corner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with build rev `2015.1.21.2979` on meta and `2015.1.21.2205` on sites. Check out [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284162/155005) for the gory details.